# CSS – Transition on border-bottom not working

Tags: css, webkit

I'm wanting to have a border bottom transition on my header navigation when the cursor hovers over the links. It was working when I first implemented this, but after adding some more code, I can't get this to work whatsoever.

My CSS looks like this:

```
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #1c2234;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom 0.2s, color 0.2s;
  transition: border-bottom 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #555;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1c2234;
}
```

[Here's a picture of the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hhw2.png)

I know that a common issue with this is not setting the border-bottom prior to hover, but I did that already and set it to transparent. The color changes upon hover, but the border isn't showing up. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The code you have provided should work. Can you provide more code / details?

Comment: Just solved this. I had `overflow: hidden;` placed on my .main-nav class and it was effecting this the border-bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured this out. I was calling `overflow: hidden` on my .main-nav class, and that was hiding my border-bottom.